# Xamarin Forms: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer

Tags: xamarin.forms

My Project type is Portable type. While deploying the project on Android I'm getting the following error:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ....\packages\Xamarin.Forms.4.6.0.726\build\Xamarin.Forms.props.

The problem is only on the Android part.

I tried deleting the following lines from .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
    <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.Maps.1.3.1.6296\lib\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Maps.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<Import Project="..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
```

After deleting these lines, I'm getting the error related to the styles.

> resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar not found.

I'm still finding my way around Xamarin, any guidance to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try restoring the nuget packages as suggested by the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official document, the example error is as following:

```
The missing file is ../../packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10/Xamarin.Forms.targets. (FormsGallery)
```

So you couldn't delete the lines as the example, you should delete the appropriate lines which have the reference for Xamarin.Forms.4.6.0.726 just like the official document.

Official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-packages-missing

In addition, you can also try to delete the code to solve the problem if they exit as the folloing link.

Link:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9093e4b-c2d8-4d66-b000-a06dd2a70f6a/error-this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer?forum=aspwebforms

Finally, you can try to change the xamarin.forms version to the Xamarin.Forms.4.6.0.726.